# Difference between "return" and "new" when constructing objects?

Tags: javascript, constructor

What is the difference between

```
function User(name) {
  return {
    'name': name,
    'isAdmin': false,
  }
}

let user = User("Jack");
```

and

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.isAdmin = false;
}

let user = new User("Jack");
```

I do not see any real difference between the syntaxes. Why was `new` even added?

Comment: `return` mean you return something from function... when you use `new` , it call your function differently, (1st) It create a constructor function, (2nd) then bind `this` (object = {}) to that constructor function, (3rd) call that constructor function and returns `this` if the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: First code example does nothing special: function just returns an object. Second code example, however, does some things behind the scenes: See: [What "new" operator does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description)

Comment: `new` creates instances,  makes more sense when constructing thousands of instances, especially when methods have been used.   Eg, you could create a function called Point, that has a method called distance, adding this distance method to every object is less efficient than just adding to the class prototype.